# Python with mamp

Tags: apache-2.2, python, mod-wsgi, mamp, mod-python

I have a MAMP 1.9 install on Lion and would like to start using python with it. Mainly to learn and develop django sites.

I am very new to python in general. In my research I found that I either need mod_python or mod_wsgi to make it work. But found little instructions on how to proceed and make it work.

So what's the difference between mod_wsgi and mod_python? which one is better?

and is there any guide on how to install it to work with mamp 1.9's apache and mysql? Ideally a step by step guide..

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both can run in embedded mode, but only mod_wsgi can run in daemonmode. Mod_wsgi is also written in C, so it has less overhead than mod_python (meaning lower memory/cpu footprint). Another reason to use mod_wsgi over python is that mod_python is  [dead](http://blog.dscpl.com.au/2010/06/modpython-project-is-now-officially.html).

Comment: FWIW. The core of mod_python is written in C as well. Depending on what parts of mod_python you use, it then has varying depth of Python code on top of that.